# Нимб как блистательное сияние, - ничего?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Его богоподобные свойства проявляются и в том, что голова его окружена
>   блистательным сиянием – нимбом.

[БЛИСТАТЕЛЬНЫЙ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

роскошный, великолепный, исключительный по своим положительным качествам ◆ Блистательный успех. ◆ Блистательное дарование. ◆ Блистательное выступление.

*редк.*, *устар*. или *поэт*. то же, что блестящий (в знач. 1 - испускающий блеск )

Comment: О ком речь, если не секрет? Нимб здесь круглый или овальный?

Comment: Ну, нимб, он всегда овальный, такой оптический казус. Видимо.

Comment: Спрашивал узнать из какой оперы. И у них не всегда овальный, а у нас так вообще зовётся окружком. Никаких искажений, циркульная кривая.

Comment: Змий! Как круглый овальный стол влияет на уместность слова *блистательный*, о чём и спрошено.

Comment: Нимб овальный не окружает, он подвешен над головой. Упс.

Comment: shampar, я простая советская старушка из экс-энкавэдешной семьи; откуда мне знать про подвешенность нимба?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*О Аллах, я прошу у Тебя Твоего сияния во имя сиятельнейшего из сияний, и всякое **сияние** Твоё **блистательное**!*
Из молитвы

*... Лазурный неба свод

Был чист и ясен. Солнечный восход

Багряными, златистыми лучами

**Блистательно** его **осиявал**...*
Н. М. Языков. Липы. 1846

**Богоподобное величие** проявляется и в том, что голова его окружена блистательным сиянием – нимбом.

**Дополнение**

[**НИМБ**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/39651)  -а; м. [лат. nimbus]
1. **сияние над головой или вокруг головы** Бога, Богоматери, святого, изображаемое (на иконах, в живописи, скульптуре) **в виде светящегося, лучистого круга**; символ святости, божественности.

НИМБ, нимба, муж. (греч. nymbos) (спец. и поэт., устар.). Сияние в виде кружка вокруг головы (на христианских иконах, у античных статуй и т.п.)
Толковый словарь Ушакова

НИМБ (от лат. nimbus, букв. — облако), **стилизованное** изображение сияния вокруг головы (символ святости или божественности), характерное для христианского, буддистского искусства.

Answer (score 1):

Блистательное его богоподобие отражается в светоносном лучистом нимбе над головой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. По картинной (реалистично-перспективной), не иконописной (с обратной перспективой) логике нимб подвешивается над головой, а не окружает её.

Comment: Но ты  ж и змий... Не веришь, что я умею читать? )))

Answer (score 1):

> Если дана свыше твердость алмазу, прозрачна зелень смарагду, если сапфир родился с голубым, анфракс с **блистательным**, как огнь, **сиянием**, назови, как хотиши, но естества его не тронешь. [Григорий Сковорода. Разговор, называемый Алфавит или Букварь мира (1760-1775)]
>
> Вас, мои ученики, ослепляет **блистательное** мирския славы **сияние**: вы позабыли, что я вам не однократно говорил: иже хощет в вас быти больший, да будет всем слуга. [архиепископ Платон (Левшин). Слово в неделю пятую Великаго Поста (1764)]

Слово *свойства* как будто пришло из научной статьи, либо употреблено не к месту: в христианской литературе богоподобные свойства доступны каждому и не связаны с нимбом.

> У Церкви она одна и единственная ― спасение человека от духовного рабства страстям и приобщение Богу через стяжание **богоподобных свойств**, главнейшими из которых являются смирение и любовь. [А. И. Осипов. Куда идет христианство (2001) // , ]
>
> Причисляя христианина к лику святых, Церковь этим не просто предлагает еще один пример веры и жизни, дает живое назидание всем верным чадам, но исповедует и утверждает великую истину христианской религии о **богоподобной природе человеческого существа** и указывает на характер той веры, которая способна возвести христианина силою Святого Духа в состояние обетования, состояние Нового Адама, гармоничного, обладающего естественными, то есть **богоподобными свойствами**. [А. И. Осипов. Святые как знак исполнения Божия обетования человеку (1994)]
>
> В конечном счете о подлинной святости свидетельствуют не наружное благочестие и не подвижничество, **а богоподобные свойства,** как очевидные знаки обетованного состояния христианина. [А. И. Осипов. Святые как знак исполнения Божия обетования человеку (1994)]
>
> Отсюда становится очевидным, насколько жизненно важно изучение пути и закономерностей духовной жизни, открытых святыми, изучение той строгой системы духовного роста, которая осуществляется в постепенном искоренении страстей и последовательном приобретении **богоподобных свойств** ― свидетелей обетованного состояния христианина. [А. И. Осипов. Святые как знак исполнения Божия обетования человеку (1994)]
>
> Смирение является той первой из добродетелей, на которой зиждется все здание совершенства святых, без которой невозможны ни правильная духовная жизнь, ни приобретение каких-либо иных **богоподобных свойств**. [А. И. Осипов. Святые как знак исполнения Божия обетования человеку (1994)]

**Его [богоподобие] проявляется и в том, что голова его окружена блистательным сиянием – нимбом.**

Comment: Но это ж пересказ искусствоведом (не очень опытным) содержания фресок!

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Угу. Вижу. Думаю.